# ERROR TypeError: buildLink is not a function (it is Object)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

I installed react native navigation. My stack navigator used to work properly until I install tab navigation. And now it gives this error

```
 ERROR  TypeError: buildLink is not a function (it is Object)

This error is located at:
    in BottomTabBar (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by TabNavigator)
    in TabNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by StackNavigator)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in Unknown (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen
    in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by your text Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by StackNavigation)
    in ThemeProvider
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by StackNavigation)
    in StackNavigation (created by App)
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in Care(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

My package version are:

```
 "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.23",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.7.1",
```

help me fix this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I did this:

```
npm uninstall @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

And then I did this:

```
npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing 7.0.0 alpha version of `@react-navigation/native` with 6.0.0 versions.

Uninstall `@react-navigation/native` and install the latest version instead:

```js
npm uninstall @react-navigation/native
npm install @react-navigation/native
```